# How to clear inputs within div based on toggle of radio button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that the user can save and return to edit. I have questions on the form that toggle a div (`class = "details`) with additional questions based on the user's answer to the previous question. There are multiple of these question types.

I'd like the answers of the sub-questions within the details div to clear if the user selects 'no' (when the sub-questions are toggled to hidden).  How would I implement that into my existing code?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XVtB8/1

jQuery:

```
$('.toggle').on('change',function(){

    var showOrHide = false;

    $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').andSelf().each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1 && $(this).prop("checked")) showOrHide = true;
    })    

    $(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);

}).change()
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Select #1:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="toggle" value="0">No    
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" class="toggle" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
</div>
<div id="details">
   <input type="text" value="123"><br>
   <input type="text" value="456">
</div>

<br>

<div>
    <label>Select #2:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="toggle" value="0">No    
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="toggle" value="1" checked="checked">Yes
</div>
<div id="details">
   <input type="text" value="789"><br>
   <input type="text" value="098">
</div>

<br>

<div>
    <label>Select #3:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" class="toggle" value="0" checked="checked">No    
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" class="toggle" value="1">Yes
</div>
<div id="details">
   <input type="text"><br>
   <input type="text">
</div>

<br>

<div>
    <label>Select #3:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio4" class="toggle" value="0">No    
    <input type="radio" name="radio4" class="toggle" value="1">Yes
</div>
<div id="details">
      <input type="text"><br>
      <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('.toggle').on('change',function(){

var showOrHide = false;

$(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').andSelf().each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1 && $(this).prop("checked")) showOrHide = true;
})    

$(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);

if (showOrHide==false){
    $(this).parent().next('#details').find('input[type=text]').val('');
    $(this).parent().next('#details').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

    // other fields type to clear   

} }).change()
```

here is un updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XVtB8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could try -

```
$('.toggle').on('change',function(){

    var showOrHide = false;
    var ClearDivs = false;

    $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').andSelf().each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 1 && $(this).prop("checked")) showOrHide = true;
        if ($(this).val() == 0 && $(this).prop("checked")) ClearDivs = true;
    })    

    $(this).parent().next('#details').toggle(showOrHide);
    if (ClearDivs) $(this).parent().next('#details').find('input[type=text]').val('');

}).change()
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/58xqM/7/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should improve the markup of your form, so that it would make sense, then go about in jQuery.

See this **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aUCAf/2/)**

### Points

- Use `<fieldset>`s to group form elements, and `<legend>` to give it a title.
- Labels are to be used with form elements, as shown in the example.