# How to clear contents of a div on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple radio buttons and on click of any radio button, it's associated div will be displayed,the divs has different inputs fields. now i want to clear contents of other div when the new div is displayed.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: where are your codes ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear inputs within div based on toggle of radio button using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279663/how-to-clear-inputs-within-div-based-on-toggle-of-radio-button-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks every one for the response, I got the solution .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to clear *all* the divs, and then replace the content of the one you actually wish to display.  If you're using jQuery, check out the [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method for a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely easy using jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` methods.

```js
  $('div').hide(); // Hide all divs on page load.

  function showDiv(id) {

    $('div').hide(); // When a radio is clicked, hide all divs.
    $('#info' + id).show(); // Show the div that is selected.

  }
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info1">Information about number 1.</div>
<input type="radio" name="info" id="1" onclick="showDiv(this.id)" />Display information about number 1
<br/>
<div id="info2">Information about number 2.</div>
<input type="radio" name="info" id="2" onclick="showDiv(this.id)" />Display information about number 1
<br/>
<div id="info3">Information about number 3.</div>
<input type="radio" name="info" id="3" onclick="showDiv(this.id)" />Display information about number 1
<br/>
<div id="info4">Information about number 4.</div>
<input type="radio" name="info" id="4" onclick="showDiv(this.id)" />Display information about number 1
<br/>
<div id="info5">Information about number 5.</div>
<input type="radio" name="info" id="5" onclick="showDiv(this.id)" />Display information about number 1
<br/>
```

I hope this helps you out.  If you need additional help, comment below.

Comment: Well, if that's what you want, then the `<div>`s that get their content removed will not be able to display their content again when their radio gets selected.  The reason: the content won't exist!